# HTML Text Cant edit width / height

Tags: html

The first code Dosent let me change the width or height
and in the second code you can edit the text witch i dont want

The First

```
        if (col === 2 && row === 2) {
            let newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
            let textBox = document.createElement("input");
            textBox.type = "text";
            textBox.style.width = "50px"; // Set the width to 50 pixels
            textBox.style.height = "50px"; // Set the height to 50 pixels
            newCell.appendChild(textBox);
            newCell.textContent = "RuRu tilted (free space)";
        } else {
            let newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
            let textBox = document.createElement("textarea");
            textBox.style.width = "500px"; // Set the width to 50 pixels
            textBox.style.height = "500px"; // Set the height to 50 pixels
            newCell.appendChild(textBox);
            newCell.textContent = words[index];
               
            index++;
```

The Second :

```
        if (col === 2 && row === 2) {
            let newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
            let textBox = document.createElement("input");
            textBox.type = "text";
            textBox.style.width = "50px"; // Set the width to 50 pixels
            textBox.style.height = "50px"; // Set the height to 50 pixels
            newCell.appendChild(textBox);
            textBox.value = "RuRu tilted (free space)";
        } else {
            let newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
            let textBox = document.createElement("textarea");
            textBox.style.width = "50px"; // Set the width to 50 pixels
            textBox.style.height = "50px"; // Set the height to 50 pixels
            newCell.appendChild(textBox);
            textBox.value = words[index]; // Set the text content for textarea
        
            index++;
        }
```

I Tried asking ChatGPT but that wasnt good help

Answer (score 0):

In first code, input field created using input has a fixed width of 50 pixels, but the textarea created using textarea has a width of 50 pixels.
the newCell.textContent line is unnecessary.

In second code value property of the input is used. So it'll be valid.

Comment: Hey Thanks For The Help what should i do to fix it